# Some webpages of the website are not working in Android using react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

Bug description:- Some webpages of the website are not working in Android but on the other side in iOS all webpages of the website are Working.

To Reproduce:-
website version:- 1.0,
webView version:- 11.26.0

```
package.json:- {
"name": "endlesstalesAndroid",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"lint": "eslint .",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-webview": "^11.26.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
"@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
"@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
"@types/react": "^18.0.24",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
"eslint": "^8.19.0",
"jest": "^29.2.1",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
"prettier": "^2.4.1",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "4.8.4"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

description:-
I tried many ways to use Webview, I also use the iframe tag in Webview but nothing happen.